# What are the various clans of Vampire the Masquerade 20th edition - Dark Ages?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages, vampire-20th-anniversary

I only am using V20 Dark ages and I was just hoping that someone could give me a paragraph of information for each of the clans so that I can get a great idea of what each one is.

Comment: Have you given the White Wolf wiki a look? https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Ages:_Vampire

Comment: This question indicates a lack of effort and research, which is why it is getting down-voted. It is still a valid question, and I hope you find the answer(s) useful, but in the future you would be better served to do some cursory research (or explain why that research is not currently possible) before asking similar questions. Good gaming!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It's right in the core rules!

The V20 core rule book has a 2-page short description on any clan<sup>1</sup>, while the *V20 Lore of the Clans* extends on each clan's history and style with a chapter for each. Or you can have it in one sentence each, from the core rulebook, character creation page:<sup>2</sup>

> Clans
>
> - Assamite — The righteous chosen of a blood cult,
>   the Assassins are masters of silent death and an arcane
>   tradition of wisdom.
> - Brujah — The Rabble are rebels and insurgents,
>   fighting passionately for their disparate causes. The
>   Brujah rage against tyranny — occasionally even their
>   own.
> - Follower of Set — Guardians of the world’s blackest
>   secrets, the Serpents are feared for what they protect,
>   and all too often seduced by it.
> - Gangrel — The nomadic Outlanders are feral and
>   wild. These solitary wanderers are the source of much
>   of the lore that likens vampires to dark beasts.
> - Giovanni — Insular and incestuous, the Necromancers
>   ply their trade in blood, money, and the souls
>   of the dead.
> - Lasombra — The shadowy, wicked Keepers nominally
>   lead the Sabbat. Clan Lasombra serves itself first
>   and its inner darkness second.
> - Malkavian — Dangerously deranged, the Lunatics
>   nonetheless possess uncanny insight.
> - Nosferatu — Disfigured and skulking, the hideous
>   Sewer Rats find themselves shunned by Kindred society,
>   but gather secrets from the darkness that hides them.
> - Ravnos — The Deceivers are adept with the craft
>   of illusion and guile, and often come to embody the
>   prejudices held against them.
> - Toreador — Lovers of the sensuous and the aesthetic,
>   the Degenerates are trapped in the stagnancy of
>   undeath.
> - Tremere — A Clan of sorcerous blood magicians,
>   the Warlocks are widely distrusted… and just as widely
>   feared.
> - Tzimisce — A Clan of fallen nobles from Eastern
>   Europe, the brilliant but monstrous Fiends now serve
>   the Sabbat.
> - Ventrue — The reluctant aristocracy of the Kindred,
>   the Blue Bloods atone for their damnation by enforcing
>   the Traditions and the Masquerade.
> - Caitiff — Claiming no Clan at all, the Caitiff exhibit
>   no common characteristics, and often find themselves
>   outcast by vampires of distinct pedigree.

The **V**ampire the **D**ark **A**ges **20** Anniversary edition core book **also** has the clans as 2-page splats<sup>3</sup> and a one-sentence descriptor for all clans in the summary, including for the clans that are Dark Ages specific.<sup>4</sup>

### Page references

1 - VtM 20 Core Rulebook, p.48-73.
2 - VtM 20 Core Rulebook, p.80-81.
3 - VDA 20 Core Rulebook, p.40-67.
4 - VDA 20 Core Rulebook, p.156.

Comment: I don't have the core rulebook Just dark ages V20.

Comment: @ColonizeroftheSun it's also in tjhe Dark Ages core book, looked up the pages for you: 40-67 and 156